# RecyclerView and Admob Items: Problems with onClickListener

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, admob

I've added a `NativeExpressAdView` inside my RecyclerView ItemList but now the onClickListener is interfering with the `NativeExpressAdView`. My "normal" Items consist of text and one larger Image. When the larger Image gets clicked on, a DialogFragment gets opened and shows detailed information of the Item. However, the `NativeExpressAdView` shouldn't run into this onClickListener. The App keeps crashing because it tries to open the not existing detailed View of the `NativeExpressAdView` ...

MainActivity

```
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ......

    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new ItemAdapter.RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), recyclerView, new ItemAdapter.ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, final int position) {
            final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable("events", events);
            bundle.putInt("position", position);
            final Event event = events.get(position);

            detailView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_thumbnail);
            detailView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    SlideshowDialogFragment newFragment = SlideshowDialogFragment.newInstance();
                    newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                    newFragment.setCancelable(true);
                    newFragment.show(ft, "slideshow");
                }
            });
           ....
           some other button onClickListener()...
           ....
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
        }
    }));
```

ItemAdapter

```
public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

private List<Event> events;
private Context mContext;

public ItemAdapter(Context context, List<Event> events){
    mContext = context;
    this.events = events;
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{ // implements View.OnClickListener {
    public ImageView thumbnail;
    public TextView event_name;
    public TextView event_date;
    public TextView event_descr;
    public TextView event_attending;
    public TextView event_maybe;

    public MyViewHolder(android.view.View view){
        super(view);
        thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_thumbnail);
        event_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tV_event_name);
        event_date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tV_event_date);
        event_descr = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tV_event_descr);
        event_attending = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tV_attending_count);
        event_maybe = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tV_maybe_count);
    }
}

public static class ViewHolderAdMob extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public NativeExpressAdView nativeExpressAdView;
    public ViewHolderAdMob(View view) {
        super(view);
        nativeExpressAdView = (NativeExpressAdView) view.findViewById(R.id.ad_nativeAdOne);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .addTestDevice("228****************************")
                .build();
        nativeExpressAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    //View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rv_items, parent, false);

    switch (viewType){
        case 1:{
            View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rv_items, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(itemView);
            break;
        }
        case 2:{
            View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.native_ad_one, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolderAdMob(itemView);
            break;
        }
    }

    return viewHolder;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position){
    Event event = events.get(position);

    switch (holder.getItemViewType()){
        case 1:{
            MyViewHolder viewHolder = (MyViewHolder) holder;
            viewHolder.event_name.setText(event.getEventName());
            viewHolder.event_date.setText(event.getEventDate());
            viewHolder.event_descr.setText(event.getEventDescription());
            viewHolder.event_attending.setText(event.getEventAttending());
            viewHolder.event_maybe.setText(event.getEventMaybeComming());

            Glide.with(mContext).load(event.getEventImage())
                    .thumbnail(0.9f)
                    .crossFade()
                    //.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .fitCenter()
                    .into(viewHolder.thumbnail);
            break;
        }
        case 2:{
            break;
        }
    }


}

@Override
public int getItemCount(){
    return events.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return  events.get(position).getViewType();
}

public interface ClickListener {
    void onClick(View view, int position);

    void onLongClick(View view, int position);
}

public static class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private ItemAdapter.ClickListener clickListener;

    public RecyclerTouchListener(final Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ItemAdapter.ClickListener clickListener){
        this.clickListener = clickListener;

        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e){
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e){

        View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)){
            clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e){

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept){

    }
}
}
```

I kind of see where the problem stems from, since the the RecyclerView is listening for input and naturally reacts to it but I kind of thought that by defining inside my MainActivity that `detailView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_thumbnail);` it will only react to "normal" items since `R.id.item_thumbnail` is an element of my "normal" items xml whereas the `NativeExpressAdView` doesn't have such an element. How can I fix this problem and get the proper functionality ??

Comment: Why did you choose to use an item touch listener instead of a click listener?

Comment: somehow I cant get the click Listener to work, that is why I went with the touchListener. I'm still trying to get it working.. I found a bunch of tutorials but none seems to work. They all suggest to implement an interface and somehow get the clickListener working, but for some reason the tutorials dont seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the click listener in `onBindViewHolder`, in your adapter, depending on the view type.

```
public static class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private final MyListClickListener clickListener;

    public ItemAdapter(MyListClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (getItemViewType(position) == ADVERT_VIEW_TYPE) {
            // do whatever you do for adverts
        } else {
            // do what you do for items and set the click listener
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    clickListener.onShowDetailViewClicked(); // pass the parameters you need to identify this particular item
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public interface MyListClickListener {

        void onShowDetailViewClicked();
    }
}
```

Comment: I just commented the `detailView,onClickListener` out and now the App keeps going for another onClickListener of another button. I guess your idea wont work, I think its the whole `recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener` that is causing the Problem, since I didn't define an action for the Ad but the input is comming in. The Admob Documentary doesn't give any information about where to point the Ads so I cant do it manually (it was probably setup to work on its own)

Comment: Yes I'm saying, instead of using an ItemTouchListener, set a normal `View.OnClickListener` in your ViewHolders, depending on the view type. You don't need to pass down the activity to the adapter, you can use a callback so the adapter doesn't start collecting stuff it doesn't need to collect.

Comment: where would I have to put the code for my DialogFragment to open and pass the corresponding item data? In my original approach I had to create a `Bundle` and `putSerializable` events (my data) + the item position inside the bundle and after that, inside the onClick create the DetailDialogFragment and attach the bundle. Where would all of this go in your approach? sorry for making it so hard, but it still dont quiet get what you are doing

Comment: You pass through an implementation of `MyListClickListener`. This can be created in your Activity as you do now, and that implementation would open the DialogFragment from your Activity. Is your code online on GitHub?

Comment: I managed to do it by passing the Activity but dont know if it is best practice. I couldn't get it your way :/ ... Thank you for your input and support tho

Comment: Create an interface (perhaps inside your Adapter) and make your Activity implement it. That way the Adapter does not know about the Activity (which is a larger concept than it) but the Activity can know about the interface inside the Adapter. Then you can refactor such that your Activity is not implementing it, but something else (to avoid having too much logic in your Activity).

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the onItemTouchListener{...} to the entire RecyclerView. It assumes that no matter where you touch, there is the detail view. But you have different types of rows in your RecyclerView. The best option would be to add touch listeners to each individual item in your ViewHolder classes.

Comment: yeah I kind of think that is the Problem here. the `onItemTouchListener{...}` - but just for the record the detailed View doesn't open regardless of where I click/touch - only the image triggers it. So you think I should remove this whole `recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener` from my `MainActivity` and try to get the buttons onClickListeners inside of the ViewHolder class back to working?

Comment: Yes, else the recycler view is consuming the event and not letting it reach the intended target

Comment: right now I'm trying inside the `onBindViewHolder` to get the onClick working but I cant seem to get the `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();` - other threads suggest to pass the MainActivity to the ViewHolder but I cant get it right.

Comment: I can't make a comment without seeing your code but you only need to pass view when creating the ViewHolder. If you need to pass context for whatever reason, you can pass the Activity you are in.

Comment: I thought you suggested that inside the `onBindViewHolder` I do `viewHolder.thumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){...});` but inside the {...} I cant call the DialogFragment

Comment: I see your case now - yes, you will need to pass the Activity you are in to your ViewHolder. You can do this in the constructor.